# Two column diagram with arrows between columns

Tags: tikz-cd

I'm taking notes for a class in Cryptography, and want the following diagram to compile.  This is supposed to represent Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange, where Alice and Bob exchange various information

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzcd}
    A & B \\
    \mathbb G,g,q\leftarrow G(1^n) & \\
    x\leftarrow\ZZ_q & \\
    h_A = g^x \arrow[r,"\mathbb{G},g,q,h_A"] & \\
    & y\leftarrow\ZZ_q \\
     & h_B = g^y\arrow[l,"h_B"] \\
    k = (h_B)^x = g^{xy} & k = (h_A)^y = g^{xy}
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
```

Up to the line including `h_A` everything seems to work will, so I'm imagining something in the `\arrow` on that line is broken.  I'd like the `\mathbb{G}, g,q,h_A` to appear above the arrow though, how can I achieve this?

I'm aware that tikzcd isn't necessarily the best package to use for this, I'm just fairly comfortable with it and when taking notes in class there's usually a time-crunch.

Edit: I've incorporated the suggested change in the comments, and it still has issues on the same line.

Comment: h_A = g^x \arrow[r,"{\mathbb{G},g,q,h_A}"] & {} \\

Comment: An alternative to @Symbol1's suggestion of having a `{}` in empty cells, is `\begin{tikzcd}[nodes in empty cells]`. The brace pair around the string is still necessary though.

Comment: Ok, it works now! If you want to write your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Symbol1 was first, so I'll leave it to her/him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

> ```
> h_A = g^x \arrow[r,"\mathbb{G},g,q,h_A"] & \\
> ```

one should have

```
h_A = g^x \arrow[r,"{\mathbb{G},g,q,h_A}"] & {} \\
```

For two reasons: First, `r,"\mathbb{G},g,q,h_A"` are five options

- `r`
- `"\mathbb{G}`
- `g`
- `q`
- `h_A"`

This makes no sense. So you should protect the commas by curly brackets.

Secondly, [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd) uses Ti*k*Z's `\matrix`. Its construction is very different from what you had learned from `tabular`, `array`, `align`, `bmatrix`, etc. In `\matrix`, by default, only non-empty entries are made into `node`s. Hence if you try to draw an arrow to an empty entry, Ti*k*Z will complain that it cannot find the destination.

By giving a pair of lonely curly brackets, Ti*k*Z will generate an empty node and now it can find the destination of the arrow. Or, as @Torbjørn T suggest, write `\begin{tikzcd}[nodes in empty cells]` which automatically make empty entry into a node.